# Problem with cross referencing using gather environment

Tags: cross-referencing, equations, amsmath

I am using gather environment to write bunch of equations. When I try to cross-reference those equations, the equation number doesn't show up. Here is my code

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\doublespacing

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}\label{eq:1}
    a=1  \nonumber \\
    b=1
\end{gather}
Equation \ref{eq:1}
\end{document}
```

The equation number is supposed to show up after "Equation" but its missing. What could be the problem? If I remove `\nonumber` then thing seems to work fine but I need `\nonumber`.

Comment: So what do you want numbered? `a=1`, `b=1`, the whole thing, or none of it? Since you're referencing something, it can't be one of the former three...

Comment: I want to reference all the equations within `gather` by one number which is same as the number for `b=1`

Comment: Please always try and post _minimal_ working examples - you include a lot of packages that are unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this you need to use the `gathered` environment from [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) and place the `\label` *outside* that environment. Another quick-and-dirty way to achieve this, without using `amsmath`, would be to use an `array`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{gathered}
    a = 1 \\ b = 2
  \end{gathered}\label{eq:1}
\end{equation}
Equation~\eqref{eq:1} and~\eqref{eq:2}.
\begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{c}
    a = 1 \\[\jot] b = 2
  \end{array} \label{eq:2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Also consider using `\eqref` instead of `\ref` for equations, since this is fully supported by `amsmath` to duplicate the behaviour of the equation number, even in other fonts.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. But the weird thing is the code that I provided above, I used it sometime before and it worked well. In any case, your solution is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to reference several equations by one number, then you can use `gathered` as Werner suggests, but I'd rather recommend the `aligned` environment in this case:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
  \begin{aligned}
    a &= 1 \\
    b &= 1
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Equation~\eqref{eq:1}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The advantage of `aligned` is that you can use alignment tabs `&` to align the equals signs (which by coincidence is not necessary in your case). Note that you should use `\eqref` and not `\ref` for referencing the equation. Moreover, it's best to always use a tie `~` between the word "equation" and the `\eqref` so that you won't have a line break inbetween. (Obviously this can't happen here since we're at the beginning of a line, but just make it a habit.)

---

If you're wondering why you're code worked before, then my best guess is that you had the `\nonumber \\` switched: with `\\ \nonumber` it works, more or less, since then the *first* equation has the label and the *second* one has no number:

[image: output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}\label{eq:1}
    a=1 \\ \nonumber 
    b=1
\end{gather}
Equation~\eqref{eq:1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer the `aligned` environment to `split`, in this case; no substantial difference, but it makes intentions clearer: it's not a single equation split across lines, but two aligned equations (that we want to consider as a block nonetheless).

Comment: I would also prefer `aligned`.  Logically `split` is for dividing up *one* equation over several lines and aligning the result, `aligned` is for a group of equations.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks for insisting, egreg and you are so right! Edited accordingly.