# Conflicts between fleqn and gathered?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I want my document formatted with `fleqn`. I was previously having issues with a missing equation number using `gather`, so following [Problem with cross referencing using gather environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101892/problem-with-cross-referencing-using-gather-environment) I switched to using `gathered` instead. This worked fine in terms of reintroducing the equation number but now centre-aligns the equations rather than them being flush left... kind of. A very simple example (equation 1) seems to remain flush left, but in my actual equation (equation 3) they are centred relative to each other.

Can someone explain why the third equation does not align like the first? I think overall I would prefer to use `gathered` rather than `gather` - apart from anything else if I want the equation number to refer to a block of equations it seems a better solution.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}


%Referencing objects/sections
%-----------------------------------
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}      % reference object types automatically
\crefformat{equation}{equation~\textup{#2#1#3}}


%Definitions of useful shortcuts (e.g. to add matrix formatting)
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\trans}{\ensuremath{^{\textup{T}}}}
\newcommand{\inv}{\ensuremath{^{-1}}}

\newcommand{\Kmat}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{K}}}
\newcommand{\yvec}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{y}}}
\newcommand{\xvec}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{x}}}
\newcommand{\xa}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{x}_{a}}}
\newcommand{\xhat}{\ensuremath{\hat{\mathbf{x}}}}
\newcommand{\Seps}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{S}_{\epsilon}}}
\newcommand{\Sa}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{S}_{a}}}
\newcommand{\Shat}{\ensuremath{\hat{\mathbf{S}}}}


%HERE BEGINS THE DOCUMENT
%------------------------------------
\begin{document}         



\section{My section}

A test equation: this seems to work fine, being both gathered and flushed left and having the equation number I want too.
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
a=b \\
b=c
\end{gathered}
\label{eq:test}
\end{equation}
This one has an issue with the equation numbering -- see the last sentence where I reference it (partially solved if I move the \textbackslash notag to the top line rather than the bottom line):
\begin{gather}
        \xhat = \xa + ( \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv )\inv \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv ( \yvec - \Kmat\xvec ) \\
        \Shat = ( \Kmat\trans\Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv)\inv \notag
\label{eq:retrieval}
\end{gather}
This one numbers OK but centre aligns the equations relative to each other:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        \xhat = \xa + ( \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv )\inv \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv ( \yvec - \Kmat\xvec ) \\
        \Shat = ( \Kmat\trans\Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv)\inv
    \end{gathered}
\label{eq:retrieval2}
\end{equation}
I want to be able to refer to \cref{eq:retrieval} and \cref{eq:retrieval2} and \cref{eq:test}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Here `gathered` just does what it's supposed to do. Use `aligned` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, `gathered` is doing what it's supposed to do; however, it's easy to modify it in such a way that it does left alignment when `fleqn` is specified.

In the code I removed all useless `\ensuremath` parts.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
% amsmath.sty, line 1253:
\renewenvironment{gathered}[1][c]{%
    \RIfM@\else
        \nonmatherr@{\begin{gathered}}%
    \fi
    \null\,%
    \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi\fi \bgroup
        \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
        \spread@equation
        \ialign\bgroup
            %%% In the original there is just \hfil
            \if@fleqn\else\hfil\fi\strut@$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil
            \crcr
}{%
  \endaligned
}
\makeatother


%Referencing objects/sections
%-----------------------------------
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}      % reference object types automatically
\crefformat{equation}{equation~\textup{#2#1#3}}


%Definitions of useful shortcuts (e.g. to add matrix formatting)
%---------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\trans}{^{\textup{T}}}
\newcommand{\inv}{^{-1}}

\newcommand{\Kmat}{\mathbf{K}}
\newcommand{\yvec}{\mathbf{y}}
\newcommand{\xvec}{\mathbf{x}}
\newcommand{\xa}{\mathbf{x}_{a}}
\newcommand{\xhat}{\hat{\mathbf{x}}}
\newcommand{\Seps}{\mathbf{S}_{\epsilon}}
\newcommand{\Sa}{\mathbf{S}_{a}}
\newcommand{\Shat}{\hat{\mathbf{S}}}


%HERE BEGINS THE DOCUMENT
%------------------------------------
\begin{document}         



\section{My section}

A test equation: this seems to work fine, being both gathered and flushed left and having the equation number I want too.
\begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
a=b \\
b=c
\end{gathered}
\label{eq:test}
\end{equation}
This one has an issue with the equation numbering -- see the last sentence where I reference it (partially solved if I move the \textbackslash notag to the top line rather than the bottom line):
\begin{gather}
        \xhat = \xa + ( \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv )\inv \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv ( \yvec - \Kmat\xvec ) \\
        \Shat = ( \Kmat\trans\Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv)\inv \notag
\label{eq:retrieval}
\end{gather}
This one numbers OK but centre aligns the equations relative to each other:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{gathered}
        \xhat = \xa + ( \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv )\inv \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv ( \yvec - \Kmat\xvec ) \\
        \Shat = ( \Kmat\trans\Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv)\inv
    \end{gathered}
\label{eq:retrieval2}
\end{equation}
I want to be able to refer to \cref{eq:retrieval} and \cref{eq:retrieval2} and \cref{eq:test}.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        \xhat &= \xa + ( \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv )\inv \Kmat\trans \Seps\inv ( \yvec - \Kmat\xvec ) \\
        \Shat &= ( \Kmat\trans\Seps\inv \Kmat + \Sa\inv)\inv
    \end{aligned}
\label{eq:retrieval3}
\end{equation}
And here we show~\cref{eq:retrieval3}

\end{document}
```

However, it's probably better using `aligned` as shown, in this particular case.

[image]

The same code, but removing `fleqn`, produces the following result, where you see that `gathered` again centers.

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks for showing me how to tweak `gathered`. I don't actually want my equations aligned at the = really,  however, it has just occurred to me I can align putting `&` at the beginning of the equation, rather than at the = sign. This has worked perfectly, so I think I will indeed use `aligned`. I was particularly curious to know why my eq 1 was left-aligned though, even in the `gathered` environment - any ideas?

Comment: PS. I knew you would complain about the `ensuremath` - I actually tried to remove for the MWE but got some weird errors - must have missed something. The thing is, I use them a lot in the text, not just in the equations.

Comment: @FionaSmith I see no problem in typing `$\Kmat$` in text instead of `\Kmat{}`. The dollars even avoid the problem of the following space. Math is math and should always be confined in explicit math mode.

Comment: Yeah, we've had this conversation before... I also use `xspace` normally which I think you would disapprove of, but it means I just type `\Kmat`. I know, lazy... but it works for me.

Comment: @FionaSmith xspace and ensuremath, you probably just killed egreg,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ;-)