# How do I align all my equations to the left side instead of right?

Tags: equations

I am trying to left align all my equations. But instead it automatically aligns itself to the right. I have tried `flaligned` but of no use. Please help.

```
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
\dot{u} = -g\sin(\theta) + rv - qw \\ 
\dot{v} = g\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta) -ru + pw \\  
\dot{w} = \frac{1}{m}(-F_{z}) + g\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta) + qu - pv \\  
\dot{p} = \frac{1}{I_{xx}}(L + (I_{yy}-I_{zz})qr) \\  
\dot{q} = \frac{1}{I_{yy}}(M + (I_{zz}-I_{xx})pr) \\  
\dot{r} = \frac{1}{I_{zz}}(N + (I_{xx}-I_{yy})pq) \\  
\dot{\phi} = p + (q \sin\phi + r \cos\phi) \tan\theta \\  \dot{\theta} = q \cos\phi - r \sin\phi \\ 
\dot{\psi} = (q \sin\phi + r \cos\phi) \sec\theta \\  
\dot{x}^{E} = cos{\theta}cos{\psi}u^{b} + (-cos{\phi}sin{\psi}+sin{\phi}sin{\theta}cos{\psi})v^{b} + (sin{\phi}sin{\psi}+cos{\phi}sin{\theta}cos{\psi})w^{b} \\  
\dot{y}^{E} = cos{\theta}sin{\psi}u^{b} + (cos{\phi}cos{\psi}+sin{\phi}sin{\theta}sin{\psi})v^{b} + (-sin{\phi}cos{\psi}+cos{\phi}sin{\theta}sin{\psi})w^{b} \\  \dot{h}^{E} = -1*(-sin{\theta}u^{b} + sin{\phi}cos{\theta}v^{b} + cos{\phi}cos{\theta}w^{b}) ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: you have not added any of the alignment points (`&`) which should be before each =

Comment: unrelated but `cos`  and `sin` should be `\cos`  and `\sin` in the last two rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned}
\dot{u} &= -g\sin(\theta) + rv - qw \\ 
\dot{v} &= g\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta) -ru + pw \\  
\dot{w} &= \frac{1}{m}(-F_{z}) + g\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta) + qu - pv \\  
\dot{p} &= \frac{1}{I_{xx}}(L + (I_{yy}-I_{zz})qr) \\  
\dot{q} &= \frac{1}{I_{yy}}(M + (I_{zz}-I_{xx})pr) \\  
\dot{r} &= \frac{1}{I_{zz}}(N + (I_{xx}-I_{yy})pq) \\  
\dot{\phi} &= p + (q \sin\phi + r \cos\phi) \tan\theta \\  \dot{\theta} &= q \cos\phi - r \sin\phi \\ 
\dot{\psi} &= (q \sin\phi + r \cos\phi) \sec\theta \\  
\dot{x}^{E} &= \cos{\theta}\cos{\psi}u^{b} + (-\cos{\phi}\sin{\psi}+\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}\cos{\psi})v^{b} + (\sin{\phi}\sin{\psi}+\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}\cos{\psi})w^{b} \\  
\dot{y}^{E} &= \cos{\theta}\sin{\psi}u^{b} + (\cos{\phi}\cos{\psi}+\sin{\phi}\sin{\theta}\sin{\psi})v^{b} + (-\sin{\phi}\cos{\psi}+\cos{\phi}\sin{\theta}\sin{\psi})w^{b} \\  \dot{h}^{E} &= -1*(-\sin{\theta}u^{b} + \sin{\phi}\cos{\theta}v^{b} + \cos{\phi}\cos{\theta}w^{b}) ,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- It is not entirely clear what you mean with *left aligned*.
- You wrongly use `aligned` environment without anchors for align of equations, for example at symbol `=` (as suggested in other answer).
- If you like to have all equation left aligned (at left `\@mathmargin`, default is 30pt), than you can use `fleqn` and modified `gathered environment as is suggested in [@egreg answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272930/conflicts-between-fleqn-and-gathered):

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article} % <---
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
% amsmath.sty, line 1253: taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272930/
\renewenvironment{gathered}[1][c]{%
    \RIfM@\else
        \nonmatherr@{\begin{gathered}}%
    \fi
    \null\,%
    \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi\fi \bgroup
        \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
        \spread@equation
        \ialign\bgroup
            %%% In the original there is just \hfil
            \if@fleqn\else\hfil\fi\strut@$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil
            \crcr
}{%
  \endaligned
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
\begin{gathered}
\dot{u} = -g\sin\theta + rv - qw \\
\dot{v} =  g\sin\phi\cos\theta -ru + pw \\
\dot{w} = \frac{1}{m}(-F_{z}) + g\cos\phi\cos\theta + qu - pv \\
\dot{p} = \frac{1}{I_{xx}}(L + (I_{yy}-I_{zz})qr) \\
\dot{q} = \frac{1}{I_{yy}}(M + (I_{zz}-I_{xx})pr) \\
\dot{r} = \frac{1}{I_{zz}}(N + (I_{xx}-I_{yy})pq) \\
\dot\phi = p + (q \sin\phi + r \cos\phi) \tan\theta \\
\dot\theta = q \cos\phi - r \sin\phi \\
\dot\psi = (q \sin\phi + r \cos\phi) \sec\theta \\
\dot{x}^{E} = \cos\theta\cos\psi u^{b} + 
                (-\cos\phi\sin\psi+\sin\phi\sin\theta\cos\psi)v^{b} + 
                (\sin\phi\sin\psi+\cos\phi\sin\theta\cos\psi)w^{b} \\
\dot{y}^{E} = \cos\theta\sin\psi u^{b} + 
                (\cos\phi\cos\psi+\sin\phi\sin\theta\sin\psi)v^{b} + 
                (-\sin\phi\cos\psi+\cos\phi\sin\theta\sin\psi)w^{b} \\  
\dot{h}^{E} = -1{\cdot}(-\sin\theta u^{b} + 
                 \sin\phi\cos\theta v^{b} + \cos\phi\cos\theta w^{b}) ,
\end{gathered}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]