# Centered left aligned `gather` environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I know that if you pass `fleqn` as an option, all `amsmath`'s environments becomes left aligned, including `gather`, however, along with that, they become flushleft.

Actually, what I'm trying to create is a left aligned `gather` environment that would be horizontally centered relatively to the page. `fleqn` is not what I need, because I want to keep the default behavior of environments, but I found a way to temporarily turn this option on. The question is about how I can center my `leftceq` environment without using additional packages as `etoolbox`?

There is a dirty workaround with `align` environment that makes me put `&` at the beginning of each line that's drastically inconvenient with lots of math equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}
\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{leftceq}{
\@fleqntrue%
\gather%
}{%
\endgather
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\verb|my environment|
\begin{leftceq}
y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x}\\
y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x
\end{leftceq}\\

\verb|desired result, faked with align environment|
\begin{align}
&y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x}\\
&y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x
\end{align}\\

\verb|default gather|
\begin{gather}
y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x}\\
y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you call the middle result "faked"? Why do you call it a "dirty workaround"? There's absolutely nothing improper, fake, or dirty about using the `align` machinery in that manner.

Comment: @Mico as you might know, if you don't put any `&` inside `align`, everything becomes right aligned. For me it's really weird, why it's not left aligned by default, so I have to create such an environment by myself. Also, I mentioned in the post why I don't like `align` approach, that's why I called it a 'facked solution'. I want to achieve such a result without spamming `&` on each and every line.

Comment: @antsher - You ask, "why [is `align`] not left aligned by default"? I believe that the default (*viz*., right-alignment if no `&` alignment point is provided) is is actually *entirely reasonable* at it greatly simplifies entering equations that actually conform to the expected use of `align`, which is to employ one or more `&` alignment points (usually, but not necessarily, placed before `=` symbols): the material up to that alignment point is right-aligned, and everything after that point left-aligned. That is *exactly* what most users would want to happen. Nothing fake about it.

Comment: This isn't a good example to illustrate why you don't like the `align` environment.  Since both `y_1` and `y_2` have the same width, the usual use of `align` with `&` preceding the `=` sign will have the exact same result.  With an example where these left-of-= elements don't have the same width, and you don't want the `=` signs aligned, it would be easier to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the “fake” but making it automatic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{leftceq}{b}
 {
  \antshar_leftceq:nn { } { #1 }
 }
 {}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{leftceq*}{b}
 {
  \antshar_leftceq:nn { * } { #1 }
 }
 {}

\seq_new:N \l__antshar_leftceq_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \antshar_leftceq:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__antshar_leftceq_seq { \\ } { #2 }
  \begin{align#1}
  & \seq_use:Nn \l__antshar_leftceq_seq { \\ & }
  \end{align#1}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Numbered
\begin{leftceq}
y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x}\\
y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x
\end{leftceq}

Unnumbered
\begin{leftceq*}
y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x}\\
y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x
\end{leftceq*}

\end{document}
```

This splits the environment's content at `\\` and places `&` in front of every line when passing the lines to `align`.

[image]

#### Bad version asked in comments

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{leftceq}{b}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \begin{align*} & \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { \\ & } \end{align*}
 }{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

I cannot recommend doing this, because if it turns out that the numbered version is necessary, one has to duplicate the code. And separating the user interface from the internal code is a plus, besides being the recommended way.

---

If you want to support nested alignments such as `cases`, I'm afraid you have to do it the hard way.

This is a fast (and quite likely it can be improved) modification of the `amsmath` code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,showframe}

\makeatletter

\newenvironment{leftceq}{%
  \start@leftceq\@ne\st@rredtrue\m@ne
}{\endalign}

\def\start@leftceq#1#2#3{%
    \let\xatlevel@#1% always \z@, \@ne, or \tw@
    \maxfields@#3\relax
    \ifnum\maxfields@>\m@ne
        \checkat@true
        \ifnum\xatlevel@=\tw@
            \xxat@true
        \fi
        \multiply\maxfields@\tw@
    \else
        \checkat@false
    \fi
    \ifingather@
        \iffalse{\fi\ifnum0=`}\fi
        \DN@{\vcenter\bgroup\savealignstate@\leftceq@#2}%
    \else
        \ifmmode
          \if@display
             \DN@{\align@recover}%
          \else
            \nomath@env
            \DN@{\@namedef{end\@currenvir}{}\@gobble}%
          \fi
        \else
            $$%
            \let\split\insplit@
            \DN@{\leftceq@#2}%
        \fi
    \fi
    \collect@body\next@
}
\def\leftceq@#1#2{%
    \inalign@true \intertext@ \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\z@
    \ifingather@\else\displ@y@\fi
    \let\math@cr@@@\math@cr@@@align
    \ifxxat@\else \let\tag\tag@in@align \fi
    \let\label\label@in@display
    #1% set st@r
    \ifst@rred\else \global\@eqnswtrue \fi
    \measure@{#2}%
    \global\row@\z@
    \tabskip\eqnshift@
    \halign\bgroup
        \span\leftceq@preamble\crcr
        #2%
}
\def\leftceq@preamble{%
   &\setboxz@h{\@lign$\m@th\displaystyle{{}##}$}%
    \ifmeasuring@\savefieldlength@\fi
    \set@field
    \hfil
    \tabskip\alignsep@
}

\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{leftceq}
y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x}\\[2ex]
y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x \\[4ex]
\begin{cases} a & x \\ b & y \end{cases} \\
y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x}\\
y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x
\end{leftceq}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess, this solution requires `xparse` package. But, actually, I don't mind it, because it's already included in my main project. Thank you for the solution, but I'd to ask two things: 1) I prefer to have minimalistic, compact code (I mean a simpler solution, rather that removing every space character to fit in one line), so is it possible to put everything together inside `NewDocumentEnvironment`? 2) Is it possible to tweak my attempt so that it will work as well?

Comment: @antshar If you need to load `xparse`, then you're running a version of LaTeX prior to 2020-10-01. I'm not sure what you mean about putting everything inside `\NewDocumentEnvironment`. It can be done, but why? Separating user interface from internal code is a plus. Your attempt cannot work, because with `fleqn` there is no centering at all.

Comment: I meant how I can make all the replacement's inside brackets: `\NewDocumentEnvironment{leftceq}{b}{<\\ replaces with \\& here>}{}`. Current solution spreads beyond environment definition.

Comment: @antshar Sorry, but I can't understand. With your approach you'd need code duplication for `leftceq` and `leftceq*`. Why would you? The way I used is actually the *recommended* way. The code will most likely sit in some external file that you `\input` in the preamble (or a personal package).

Comment: Actually, I don't need a starred version of the environment. if you don't mind, this way would be the best for my needs.

Comment: @antshar I added the simple modification, but I still advise you not doing this way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and for taking into account all my whims. I appreciate that!

Comment: I've just noticed that due to such a replacement, additional spacing `\\[1em]` becomes impossible. Is there any way to support it?

Comment: @antshar That can be solved, stay tuned

Comment: Also I came across with a problem that if I have any other environment like `cases` inside `leftceq`, such a direct replacement of `\\­`, breaks nested environments. Probably it worth giving a try to my attempt and center somehow or come up with something else.

Comment: @antshar I added a new version.

Comment: Thank you for you so much!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also need an `-ed` version of the environment. I didn't say that because I thought I can easily modify the answer, however, with your last solution that's perfect for me I couldn't manage to make it work with arguments (`[c]`, `[t]`, `[b]`). Despite my own answer that work in simple cases, the spaces a bit wrong though when the line breaks on math operators. So I'd rather stick with your workaround. I would be really grateful if you could add `leftceqed` version as well.

Answer (score 0):

After long researches and collecting information bit by bit, found the solution.

They key is to turn `fleqn` for `gathered` instead of `gather` and then put it inside `\[ \]` that will make it centered. However, unfortunately, a direct replacement of `\gather ... \endgather` with `\gathered ... \endgathered` doesn't work, because `gathered` doesn't seem to support option `fleqn`. Luckily, I found [this egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272935/213149) that points out how change it the way it begins to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, showframe}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{gathered}[1][c]{%
    \RIfM@\else
        \nonmatherr@{\begin{gathered}}%
    \fi
    \null\,%
    \if #1t\vtop \else \if#1b\vbox \else \vcenter \fi\fi \bgroup
        \Let@ \chardef\dspbrk@context\@ne \restore@math@cr
        \spread@equation
        \ialign\bgroup
            %%% In the original there is just \hfil
            \if@fleqn\else\hfil\fi\strut@$\m@th\displaystyle##$\hfil
            \crcr
}{%
  \endaligned
}


\newenvironment{leftceq}{
\[\bgroup%
\@fleqntrue%
\begin{gathered}%
}{%
\end{gathered}\hskip1.5pt%
\egroup\]%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\verb|leftceq|
\begin{leftceq}
y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x} \\
y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x
\end{leftceq}

\verb|gather|
\begin{gather}
y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x}\\
y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x
\end{gather}

\verb|gathered in mathmode|
\[
\begin{gathered}
y_1 = C_1e^{-4x}+C_2e^{-5x}+C_3xe^{-5x}\\
y_2 = C_1e^{6x}+C_2e^{-9x}\cos x+C_3e^{-9x}\sin x
\end{gathered}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]